# How to pass the name of a link, which is retrieved from database to another page in php

Tags: php, mysql

I like to pass the value `$row['name']` which is from database to another page show.php... Hlp

```
<a href="show.php" name="<?php $ref=$row['name']; ?>">
<?php echo $row['id'];echo '.'.$row['name'];?>
</a>
```

Comment: You should be more specific. You can put this value to url and use `$_GET` to extract it. You can store it at session or even retrieve it from db (I don't know your idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="show.php?ref=<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
<?php echo $row['id'];echo '.'.$row['name'];?>
</a>
```

At show.php

```
echo $_GET['ref']
```

Comment: It works.. But i am encountering a   " ?>  along with the data

Comment: @Bright Check your ref variable at link. `show.php?ref=name`, `name` is your text which will be visible after you `echo $_GET['ref']`. Maybe you will see at `show.php?ref=name?>`. In that case check your code and remove unnecessary symbols.

Comment: This is my link:             <a 
style="font-size:18px; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; color:#09F;"
href="show.php?ref=<?php echo $row['name'];?>
">
<?php echo $row['id'];echo '.'.$row['name'];echo "<hr><br/>";}?>
</a>

Comment: @Bright
1. This code isn't working. You have `}`. You should remove it.
2. It's html mess. You should show <hr /><br /> after </a> tag.
3. Check html source code at browser. Find `ref=`. What value inside it?
4. If it will be ok, check script where you call `$_GET['ref']`
5. Correct code will be: `<a style="font-size:18px; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; color:#09F;" href="show.php?ref=<?php echo $row['name'];?> ">
 <?php echo $row['id']; echo '.'.$row['name']; ?>
</a><hr><br />`

Answer (score 0):

well if you are inside the while condition i.e.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo $row['username']; //outputs a username

echo '<a href="http:site.com/page.php?id='. $row['username']. '" >' .$row['username']. '</a>';
}
```

or simply you can assign the fetched result to a variable and include it in a url like this:

```
$username = $row['username'];

echo '<a href="http://www.site.com/page.php?id=' . $username. '">' . $username. '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a href="show.php?name='.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a>';
```

From there, get the name on show.php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = " . $_GET['name']);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['name'];
// echo any fields you want to display
}
```

This is just a guideline. You're open to sql injection.